# Why does \loop behave differently depending on order of its contents?

Tags: tex-core, loops

Just a question out of curiosity. I tested the code below, and first two `{\loop...\repeat}` commands returned `\TeX!\quad` six times, and others returned it five times. Why do only first two `{\loop...\repeat}` commands return `\A` (= `\TeX!\quad`) six times? What difference is there between first two commands and remaining commands?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcount\cnt@a
\def\A{\TeX!\quad}
\def\B{\advance\cnt@a by-1}
\def\C{\ifnum\cnt@a>0}
\cnt@a=5
{\loop\A\B\C\repeat}

{\loop\A\C\B\repeat}

{\loop\B\A\C\repeat}

{\loop\B\C\A\repeat}

{\loop\C\A\B\repeat}

{\loop\C\B\A\repeat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use back-ticks to highlight in-line code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definitions of `\B` and `\C` are the problem:

```
\def\B{\advance\cnt@a by-1}
\def\C{\ifnum\cnt@a>0}
```

TeX does not stop at the end of the numbers, but continue expanding until it finds a token, which is not a digit, e.g.:

```
\B1234\relax
```

will decrease `\cnt@a` by -11234, not by -1. Or

```
\B\C
```

Then the `\ifnum` is executed *before* the counter is decreased.

Both cases are fixed by appending a space after the number, which ends the number and is ignored for typesetting:

```
\def\B{\advance\cnt@a by-1 }
\def\C{\ifnum\cnt@a>0 }
```

Alternatively, the registers `\m@ne` or `\z@` can be used:

```
\def\B{\advance\cnt@a by\m@ne}
\def\C{\ifnum\cnt@a>\z@}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcount\cnt@a
\def\A{\TeX!\quad}
\def\B{\advance\cnt@a by-1 }
\def\C{\ifnum\cnt@a>0 }
\cnt@a=5
{\loop\A\B\C\repeat}

{\loop\A\C\B\repeat}

{\loop\B\A\C\repeat}

{\loop\B\C\A\repeat}

{\loop\C\A\B\repeat}

{\loop\C\B\A\repeat}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]